# What is the difference between $('#selectID').find(':selected').val() and $('#selectID').val() for non-multi select elements?

Tags: jquery

When working with a `select` element (`multiple=false`) with many options, what is the difference (functional, speed, etc) between doing the following in jQuery:

```
$('#selectID').find(':selected').val()
```

and

```
$('#selectID').val()
```

Comment: What DOM do you have?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not exactly sure what you mean. HTML5 on variety of browsers. I clarified that the question pertains to jQuery.

Comment: I'd suggest running a test on jsperf, but I really doubt there will be a difference enough to give you reason to chose one over the other, other than what you prefer to type and look at.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for pointing me to [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/find-selected-val); it doesn't seem there is much difference in speed.

Comment: @queuebit Since you're using `selectID` as the ID attribute, I'd assume that it is unique on your page. And if it is unique; and the `.val()` would work just fine.

Comment: @hjpotter92 If you wanted to summarize in an answer, I can accept it. Otherwise I will summarize myself later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `<select>` element with `multiple=false` there seems to be no functional difference.

jsPerf shows the [`.val()` to be much faster](http://jsperf.com/find-selected-val/2) than the additional finds.